# SQL SELECT Query with returning hierarchical data

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I have got a table which goes something like this:

```
State_id | County_id|  City_id |     Name      |    Additional_Name
-----------------------------------------------------------------
   1     |     0    |     0    |   California  |        State
   1     |     1    |     0    |   Los Angeles |        County
   1     |     1    |     1    |   Los Angeles |        City
   1     |     2    |     0    |   San Diego   |        County
   1     |     2    |     1    |   San Diego   |        City
   2     |     0    |     0    |   Texas       |        State
   2     |     1    |     0    |   Harris      |        County
   2     |     1    |     1    |   Houston     |        City
```

It goes on for 10,000 rows. What I'm trying to accomplish is to build a SELECT statement which will result in:

```
  State       |   County     |     City
 -------------------------------------------
  California  |  Los Angeles |    Los Angeles
  California  |  San Diego   |    San Diego
  Texas       |  Harris      |    Houston
```

As you can see i want to select every city and display it's state, and county. The state_id, county_id, city_id and Additonal_Name columns should be essential in solving this problem, but i have no idea how to use them.

Comment: if possible, separate that information into three tables. That is a poorly designed database, and will only cause you more headaches in the future. This would fall under 'Normalizing' a database.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This will get your data, using your current table structure:

```
SELECT t2.[Name] AS [State]
    ,t3.[Name] AS County
    ,t1.[Name] AS City
FROM MyTable t1
JOIN MyTable t2 -- get state
    ON t2.State_id = t1.State_id
       AND t2.County_id = 0
       AND t2.City_id = 0
JOIN MyTable t3 -- get county
    ON t3.County_id = t1.County_id
       AND t3.State_id = t1.State_id
       AND t3.City_id = 0
WHERE t1.City_id > 0 --(or use t1.Additional_Name = 'City'
```

---

### But Really:

You should be normalizing your database into three separate tables:

1. `City`
2. `State`
3. `County`

This will make using your data, and writing queries - muchh simpler and readable.

The tables would look something like this:

**State**

```
ID Name
 1 California
 2 Texas
```

**County**

```
ID Name
 1 Los Angeles
 2 San Diego
 3 Harris
```

**City**

```
ID StateID CountyID Name
 1 1       1        Los Angeles
 2 1       2        San Diego
 3 2       3        Houston
```

Hopefully you can see how much easier that is to manage things. You can choose to add a `StateID` to the `County` table to normalize further. But I'll keep my answer short.

Select the same data from these new tables with a similar query:

```
SELECT state.[Name] AS [State]
    ,county.[Name] AS County
    ,city.[Name] AS City
FROM MyCity city
JOIN MyState state ON state.ID = city.StateID -- get state
JOIN MyCounty county ON county.ID = city.CountyID -- get county
```

Comment: I queried the data sample i showed in the topic and got 42 records, while i should get 3 (as there are 3 cities). There were all kinds of data in State column, like Los Angeles, Harris, Houston etc. Thank you for all the normalization advices and I probably will get to it eventually, but for now the form of the table must stay as it is.

Comment: This time i get: 

     'California      Los Angeles     Los Angeles'

Texas         Los Angeles Houston

California      Los Angeles Los Angeles

Texas         Los Angeles Houston

California      San Diego San Diego

California San Diego San Diego

California Harris         Los Angeles

Texas         Harris         Houston

California Houston         Los Angeles

Texas         Houston          Houston' '/code'

Comment: I see you reuse ID values for county, if the state is different. Again, this table structure is bad for maintenance and querying. edited post to work

Comment: Now it works perfectly. Thank you so much for your help and time consumed. I'm aware that this table needs normalizing and "splitting" into three tables, but it was a thing i had to do with this form. Thank you again and have a great day!